# Nodejs is there after uninstalling it in macOS

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to uninstall nodejs in mac but after uninstalling it, Nodejs is still there. I have tried `brew uninstall node` and `brew uninstall node --force` it is uninstalling one version of node but my old version of nodejs is still there. 
I Runned

```
node -v
```

it is  showing

```
v4.8.4
```

after the uninstall process

Comment: Run `which node` and figure out where it is installed.

Comment: Try `brew cleanup node`

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from this GitHub [SOURCE](https://gist.github.com/TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef). It worked for me.

**Run these steps**

```
# first:
lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom | while read f; do  sudo rm /usr/local/${f}; done
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*

# To recap, the best way (I've found) to completely uninstall node + npm is to do the following:

# go to /usr/local/lib and delete any node and node_modules
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo rm -rf node*

# go to /usr/local/include and delete any node and node_modules directory
cd /usr/local/include
sudo rm -rf node*

# if you installed with brew install node, then run brew uninstall node in your terminal
brew uninstall node

# check your Home directory for any "local" or "lib" or "include" folders, and delete any "node" or "node_modules" from there
# go to /usr/local/bin and delete any node executable
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
ls -las

# you may need to do the additional instructions as well:
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
```